# Get Screen size in Swift as Integer

Tags: ios, swift

For positioning an element random in the screen but within the boundarys I need the resolution/screen size in swift. I already fount out how to get it with CGGraphics. Unfortunately I have to calculate a bit and need it as type `UInt32`, not `CGFloat`. I cannot use casting that way. Any ideas?

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
//What I want to do
let screenHeight = screenSize.height-arc4random_uniform(screenSize.height)
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want random X and Y positions for your element you can do something like this:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let randomXPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.width)))
let randomYPos = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height)))
```

### Swift 4.2

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let randomXPos = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenSize.width)
let randomYPos = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<screenSize.height)
```

Comment: There is a difference between `arc4random` and `arc4random_uniform`.

Comment: Swift 3: `UIScreen.main.bounds`

Comment: let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds; in swift 3

Answer (score 4):

To get the value direct in Int use this code

```
var bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    var w:Int  = Int(self.bounds.size.width)
    var h:Int  = Int(self.bounds.size.height)
```

All you have to do is that convert the returning value from CGFloat to Integer

Use following code to Get the value of screen height width and then convert the CGFloat to Int

```
var bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
var width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
var height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height
```

> SWIFT 4.2

```
let bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
let width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
let height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height
```

Answer (score 2):

you try like this

```
let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
let screenWidth = screenSize.width * 0.75
```

Comment: for swift4 :- let SCREEN_BOUNDS: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need:

```
let screenHeight = screenSize.height - CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(screenSize.height)))
```